# Could not find installable ISAM when importing an Excel file into an Access db

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I'm currently trying to get the following code to work:

```
Dim s As Long: s = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim acc As Object
  Set acc = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  acc.Visible = True
  acc.OpenCurrentDatabase Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Database.accdb"
  acc.CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Blad1;", 128 ' dbFailOnError = 128
  acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acspreadsheettypeexcel12xml, _
        TableName:="Blad1", _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1$A1:N" & s
  acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
  acc.Quit
  Set acc = Nothing
```

I see that the line `acc.CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Blad1;"` is working fine since it deletes all the data in the table. Everything seems to run fine until `acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

Microsoft Access opens and the following error appears:
[image]

Which means as much as 'Error 3170: Could not find installable ISAM'

I've been searching for an answer for quite a while now but I can't seem to find anything that really solves the problem. What do you guys think the solution is?

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/3041386/-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-when-you-refresh-a-data-table-in-excel)?

Comment: I don't have any connections listed in there

Comment: I have your problem. If you reach solution, help me. my related question is in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968735/export-dbf-from-a-table-in-excel-with-consider-and-pay-attention-to-datatype-an). Thanks. Seems guys not eager for this matter!