# Export DBF from a Table in Excel (with consider and pay attention to Datatype and length of fields)

Tags: vba, excel, dbf, dbase

I'm working in an macro container Excel `Workbook` on a `Table` in `Sheet1`.

And have to create DBF file from the `Table` With `VBA` macro.

1-note that after 2003, Excel not support `DBF` format, thus I cannot use bellow...

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:="C:\insurance.dbf", _
    FileFormat:=xlDBF4, _
    CreateBackup:=False
```

So, please write a `VBA` macro which save `DBF` from a `Filtered` range (a range with multi `Area`) of that `Table` in MS-Excel `Worksheet`.

2- May i define my customized data type to each field in created `DBF` by above hypothetical `VBA` macro?

**I Don't want opening or edit an existing `*.dbf`. I'm just going create and save `DBF` with customized `Datatype` and `length` if possible; from a multi area filtered range table in `Worksheet` with a `VBA` `function`.**

Can we use:

```
Dim appAccess as Object
set appAccess = CreateObject("Acss.App")
...
appAccess.Run ...
```

For that?! (As an idea)

Thanks.

For more description:

Are there any quick and quiet way to export `dbf` file from a range of Excel? If existing direct way to create and save `dbf` file from that range, that is better.

Comment: In Access,  import your excel sheet,  and in Access export the table as dbf.

Comment: I want that has done programmatically and without user prompt . (Silent) Which code can write in Excel module with this approach, that get me `.dbf` format result from an initial Excel `Range`?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not perfect. Just refer to it.

```
Sub myQuery()
    Dim path As String, pathExcel As String
    Dim dbName As String
    'Dim App As Access.Application
    Dim App As Object

    'Set App = New Access.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set App = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\"
    pathExcel = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    dbName = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Database1.accdb" '<~~ in access, you create accdb(Database1.accdb) before.

    App.OpenCurrentDatabase dbName

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Sheet1", pathExcel '<~~from sheet1 to access

    App.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "DBase IV", path, acTable, "Sheet1", "test.dbf" '<~~ access table to dbf
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Sheet1"

    App.DoCmd.Close
    App.DoCmd.Quit
    App.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: I want code works in memory (silent) without save (temp) data and using path and file name.

Comment: Is there any quick and quite way to export directly `dbf` from excel range?; as using `ADOBE` connection or ect...